# Allow custom search string in new nav tabs

Tags: feature-request, search, new-nav

Allow the new nav bar that accepts only tags to either accept a search string in addition or in place of.

I want to create a custom tab that uses the nice sorting features of the new nav, as well as leverages the power of search - *without* having to constantly store the search string. It should be its own tab.

This is an example of one of the searches that currently does not work with the new nav feature: score:1 hasaccepted:no closed:no duplicate:no is:question